# Cannot avoid the error marks on md elements of Angular material in visual studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, element, intellisense, angularjs-material

[Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNaH9.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXWTv.jpg)

Cannot avoid the error marks on md elements of Angualr material in visual studio 2013

Comment: Please take a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Material design in your project, and is available in the file you are working on